# Mouse.hide() does not work over a hyperlink on a htmlText

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Im using `Mouse.hide();` function to hide the mouse cursor on AS3 using flash professional cs5.5 (compiling for AIR 2.5). Over almost the compete scene the mouse pointer is hidden but if you have a text field with html content on, the mouse reappear when you hover an hyperlink `<a>`. I need the link to be clickable but with no mouse cursor since the application is intended to run on a touchscreen.

Comment: Hmm I thought mobile apps on AIR already hide the cursor for you, did you test on a mobile device and got a mouse cursor?

Comment: It will not run on a mobile platform, will run on a pc with touchscreen

Comment: If you control the HTML content then use CSS to change the `cursor` attribute. If you don't, the textfield needs to get a custom codeline to disable mouse visibility.

Comment: can you show the second solution? the custom codeline.

Answer (score 0):

`Mouse.hide()` in AIR does not actually work everywhere as in flash (checked mac, yet?)

A workaround [here](http://blog.formatlos.de/2008/11/16/air-hiding-the-mouse/), has been floating around as the solution:

```
stage.nativeWindow.activate();
stage.nativeWindow.orderToBack();
stage.nativeWindow.orderToFront();
Mouse.hide();
```

Comment: This does not work (tested on windows). Same problem, if i hover a hyperlink it shows the cursor

Comment: i concur...Sometimes it will work, sometimes it will not...As the fix implies, it seems to be some kind of runtime issue. I also worked around this once by writing an applescript (batch file or shell script would work too) that opens opens the air app, then opens a dummy app next, or terminal, or something invisible, then makes the air app active in front again...This hid the mouse maybe 95% of the time. It's a stupid bug.

Comment: also, a slight modification to the above script, I had added `dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));` after the window ordering, as the idle cursor may still be floating visible until deployed again.